# Why will we pasken like Beis Shammai when Moshiach comes if the reason why we follow Beis Hillel is related to the fact that they had more members

Tags: halacha-theory, messiah, mishna

It is my understanding per [this](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Shabbat.1.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) Mishna that the reason why we rule like Beis Hillel in the majority of cases is related to the rule of "following the majority". I know there are other reasons given (i.e. Hillel was more humble, which is shown a few times over on [Shabbat 31a](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.31a.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) but by strict reasoning I believe this would be the rationale. However, it is my understanding that there are some Kabbalistic [sources](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/21794/22195) that say that in the days of Moshiach we will follow Beis Shammai. If we are to say that the reason for us following Beis Hillel is by dint of the fact that they were the majority, then this shift doesn't make sense, I can't imagine that when Moshiach comes, Beis Shammai will suddenly outnumber Beis Hillel. I am just wondering how all of the mechanics will work to shift our psak from Beis Hillel to Beis Shammai given that according to my understanding it is the majority rules which will presumably not change upon the coming of Moshiach.

Comment: "How will the details of this eschatological event work out in practice" is rarely an answerable question before it does.

Comment: And why can't you imagine this? Individual members of the Sanhedrin at that time can decide just that - that they find Beis Shammai's arguments more convincing - and end up being a majority.

Comment: @Meir I'm not sure if I understand. Doesn't majority mean having more physical members, which is set in stone for time immemorial?

Comment: First, it could be metaphoric -- today we need halakhah founded on rachamim (Hillel was nasi) and le'asid lavo we'll be better off with halakhah founded on din (Shammai was av beis din). But technically, it can happen. If the messianic Sanhedrin is greater in number and wisdom, than that in the days of Batei Hillel veShamai they could re-vote on any decision that earlier Sanhedrin made.

Comment: @AlexanderMermelstein Yes, but many determinations of halachah in one generation can be reopened in a future generation (see Mishneh Torah, Hil. Mamrim 2:1). So at the time when these laws were decided, Beis Hillel were the majority; but in a future Sanhedrin these issues can be brought up again for a discussion and a revote, and this time the majority of its 71 members may decide differently.

Comment: @MichaBerger They don't even need to be greater in number and wisdom. That's only in order to set aside an earlier Sanhedrin's gezeiros and takkanos (see Hil. Mamrim 2:1-2).

Comment: @Meir - assuming said Sanhedrin decides to hold like the Rambam. But Rashi, Ritva, Ran, even the Chinukh (for whom this is more rare) doesn't. So I just assumed. I could be wrong. Hopefully we'll resolve the question soon enough. Would be nice.

Comment: @Meir So the majority of the Sanhedrin ruled like beis hillel and that's why the halacha is like them? It's not the fact that there more students in beis hillel than beis shammai?

Comment: @AlexanderMermelstein Ultimately it comes down to a vote of the supreme Beis Din (i.e., Sanhedrin). That Beis Hillel were greater in number means that when it came time to vote, their opinion (generally) prevailed. (Keep in mind that "students" here doesn't mean yeshivah bochurim; even senior members of the court are, in the formal sense at least, "students" or "disciples" of the Nassi and the Av Beis Din.)